# Angular 2 - Error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I´m getting the "error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target." when I try to reject a promise but I think that the code respects the signatures. Any idea?

In fact that works when I use in a web application, now I´m trying to compile it using nativescript.

The code:

```
login(): Promise<User> {
    // get the user here 
    if (error) {
         return (Promise.reject<User>("Error");
    }else {
         return Promise.resolve(new User());
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call the method? Edit the post please.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, I was compiling with es5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error! It was compiling with es5. I change the target to es6 on tsconfig.json and it works.